# Is there a name for collections of subsets that generate a neigbourhood base?

Tags: general-topology

I am in need of collections $\mathcal N$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ with the following property: for all $x\in X$ and open $U\ni x$ there is a $V\in\mathcal N$ such that $x\in\operatorname{int}V$ and $V\subseteq U$. The sets $V$ are not necessarily open so $\mathcal N$ is not a base. $\mathcal N$ is such a collection if and only if, for all $x$, $\mathcal N_x=\{V\in\mathcal N\mid x\in\operatorname{int}V\}$ is a neighbourhood base at $x$, but I do not want to specifically associate the subsets in $\mathcal N$ to elements of $X$. Is there a name for such collections as $\mathcal N$?

Comment: When I was first taught point set topology, these sets were called neighborhoods.

Comment: The definition is more restrictive than  just any subset of neighbourhoods.

Comment: All such $V$ are neighborhoods.  Some neighborhoods are not in $N$.  What are you looking for?

Comment: For example, the other day I needed a name for sets which are contained in the closure of their interior. I searched and found "semi open". Hopefully that is standard. I didn't happen to know that name. Now, I need this: Defn: A *blah* is a collection of subsets of X such that ... the property I stated in the question. What I am looking for is *blah*. I searched but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call it an interior network maybe. A network is a family like a base but whose elements need not be open. So the extra demand that the interiors form a base (which is what you want) could justify such a name.
There is no standard name for it, as it seems a useless notion (as opposed to networks).

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to have a reference? Network and topology searches just get technology related terms. Anyway, its not useless to me. I have the unhappy circumstance to be forced to the notion of a presheaf but on closed sets rather than open ones.  There is no avoiding it. Associations of sets to subsets in such *N* as in the question works in my case.

Comment: @user2747939 look for cardinal functions in topology. There are several overview papers.

Comment: Yes! Got that. Never would have found it. Thanks.